# How to show DB data in my HTML page in Django website?

Tags: python, django, database, view, vs-web-site-project

I checked my DB table and the data I entered is on my db, but I see nothing on my HTML page in my Django website.

this is my View:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from .models import Article


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
context = {
    "articles": Article.objects.filter(status="publish").order_by("-publish")
}
return render(request, 'website/home.html', context)
```

This is my model:

```
   from django.db import models
   from django.utils import timezone       
  # Create your models here.
  class Article(models.Model):
   STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('Draft', 'Draft'),
    ('Published', 'Published')
)
title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
description = models.TextField()
thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to="images")
publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

this is my HTML page:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
{% for article in articles %}
<img src="{{ article.thumbnail.url}}" alt="{{ article.title }}">
<h1><a href="{{ article.slug }}"> {{ article.title }}</a></h1>
<small>{{ article.publish }}</small>
<p>{{ article.description }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no choice called publish. 
need to change it to published. like this : 
context

```
 = {
    "articles": Article.objects.filter(status="published").order_by("-publish")
}
```

because your choices are :

```
 STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('Draft', 'Draft'),
    ('Published', 'Published')
```

Answer (score 0):

In example you've given, it appears a ListView would more easily achieve what you are trying to do. Class-based views aren't always better solutions but can be a lot better to quickly implement common tasks such as listing objects from a db.

### views.py

A list view will take in a model as a parameter and hand over the context data to the template (by default the context data will be called *object_list*).

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from .models import Article

class ArticleListView(ListView):

    model = Article

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

### urls.py

Since this is a class-based view, you will need to handle it slightly differently in your urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from article.views import ArticleListView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', ArticleListView.as_view(), name='article-list'),
]
```

### HTML template

By default, this class-based view will look for a HTML template called *article_list.html*, within your applications templates directory. If you wish to change this template name, you will need to specify its location from the templates dir, as so:  `template_name = "myapp/a_different_name.html"`.

Your article_list.html will now look like this.

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
{% for article in object_list %}
    <img src="{{ article.thumbnail.url}}" alt="{{ article.title }}">
    <h1><a href="{{ article.slug }}"> {{ article.title }}</a></h1>
    <small>{{ article.publish }}</small>
    <p>{{ article.description }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

More information on class-based views can be found here [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/).